# Getting uilabel height for bold attributed text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uifont

My code to calculate height required to for label is as follows:

```
 -(float)frameForText:(NSString*)text sizeWithFont:(UIFont*)font constrainedToSize:     (float)width{
       NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary   dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
       CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){width, CGFLOAT_MAX} options:      (NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:attributesDictionary
                                  context:nil];
      // This contains both height and width, but we really care about height.
       return frame.size.height;

  }
```

I have called it as follows from below code to calculate height firs then used it to draw label

```
    //form attributed title
    NSString *str_title =@"This is sample title to calculate height";
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    [paragraphStyle setLineSpacing: 2.0f];
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"PTSans-Bold" size:10], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle };
    NSAttributedString *attributed_title = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str_title attributes:attributes];
    //calculate height required for title
    float comment_height = [self frameForText:str_title sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"PTSans-Bold" size:10] constrainedToSize:250];

    UILabel *lbl_title;
    //use calculated height here
    lbl_title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 5, 250, title_height)];
    lbl_title.numberOfLines = 0;
    lbl_title.attributedText = attributed_title;
```

This works fine when font is "PTSans-Regular" and gives exact uilabel height. But, it is not working for "PTSans-Bold" by above code.

How should I return exact UIlabel needed to write "PTSans-Bold" text with label of width 250, font's size 10 and paragraph line spacing equal to 2? Note: the "PTSans-Bold" is not system font, it's font I have added.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is easyiest way to find `UILabel` text height dynamically height for below `iOS7`

```
CGSize fontSize = [uilabel.text sizeWithFont:uilabel.font];
NSLog(@"height %f",fontSize.height);
```

for `iOS7`

```
float heightIs =[uilabel.text boundingRectWithSize:uilabel.frame.size options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:uilabel.font } context:nil].size.height;
```

Comment: sizeWithFont Deprecated in iOS 7.0. Use sizeWithAttributes: instead.

Answer (score 2):

use the below method after setting font and every properties.

```
- (CGFloat)getHeight:(UILabel *)label{

      CGSize sizeOfText = [label.text boundingRectWithSize: CGSizeMake( self.bounds.size.width,CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                                  options: (NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                               attributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:label.font
                                                forKey:NSFontAttributeName]
                                                  context: nil].size;

    return sizeOfText.height; 

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved this problem with below code:

```
-(float)heightOfAttrbuitedText:(NSAttributedString *)attrStr width:(CGFloat )width{

    CGRect rect = [attrStr boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, 10000) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:nil];
    return rect.size.height;
}
```

Comment: I would use `0` as height in this case.  It is exactly what you seem to want (every height allowed).  I put my version into a category,